# Isomorphism and crossed product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When I consider isomorphism of matrix rings and crossed product, I want to know the answer of the following question. Thanks.

Let $R$ be a ring and let
$$T(R)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
0 & a & d\\
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}\;\middle\vert\; a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$
If $M$ is a monoid and $R[M]$ is the monoid ring, I know that there is an isomorphism
$$T(R)[M]\cong T(R[M])$$ 
defined in the obvious way. For a crossed product $R\ast M$ with twisting $f\colon M\times M\to U(R)$ and action $\omega\colon M\to\operatorname{Aut}(R)$, I want to know if the isomorphism
$$T(R)\ast M\cong T(R\ast M)$$
is true? I am not sure for this result. Moreover, is this result also true for the upper triangular matrix ring $U_n(R)$ and the full matrix ring $\mathrm{M}_n(R)$?

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA00h.png))

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/66ecbc0f-5586-45de-8ace-5fa066d819e9/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Why do you insist on posting a picture? the result is ugly and Zev did all the typing work for you!

Comment: I agree with @tomasz. Zev's edit was perfectly legitimate, and the question would still make sense even if the image somehow got deleted. -1

Comment: He seems to have edited the picture, which is not reflected in the recent edit by Alex. Anyway @user94423, please use MathJax instead of uploading pictures of formulas.

Comment: @ChristophPegel Ah, thanks, hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Because I am not familar with the MathJax,  sorry for my posting a picture! Now I am leaning how to use it, thank you very much!